# How can I specify that a sanbox be created on a specific instance?

Tags: sandbox

I looked at the [Sandbox Setup Tips](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm), but didn't see anything and I didn't see anything in the process of creating a sandbox for doing this.

I'd like to be able to specify which Salesforce instance (e.g., cs9, cs10, etc.) a sandbox is created on.  The reason being that I've created some triggers/classes on cs9 which have api version 26 (Winter '13) and I created a new sandbox which got created on cs10 which is still on api version 25 (Summer '12).

I cannot move any of the classes/triggers that I created on cs9 to cs10.

```
Problem: Invalid api version:26.0
```

I know that I can change the api versions of the classes and triggers, but would rather not do so (might have some new api 26 functionality that I'd have to remove/refactor...ugh).

I'd like to be able to specify that my new sandbox be created on a api version 26 instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - you can't.

Salesforce upgrades their sandboxes in two (or more) batches. Depending on where your sandbox is located, it either gets upgraded early or it gets upgraded late(r). It's typically a matter of weeks.

If you think about it - when you refresh a sandbox it creates an exact copy of your Prod org. Since your Prod org, most likely, is still on v25, your new sandbox will need to be directed to a v25 instance. Otherwise, it would need to be upgraded while being refreshed.

Any sandbox refreshed after Aug 31 is directed to an instance that will remain longer on v25. The only way you can (could have) controlled the instance is by refreshing on or before Aug 31.

Salesforce always posts instructions about these dates. You can find the instructions for the Winter '13 upgrade window [on the Product blog](http://blogs.salesforce.com/product/2012/07/winter-13-sandbox-preview-instructions.html).

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense - I created a brand new sandbox on 8/31 on cs9 which was api-25, and it upgraded to api-26 later.  Today on 9/25 when I create a sandbox it doesn't get created on cs9, like you said probably because it copies from production (api-25).  Looks like I'll have to wait until Oct. 13 and try to plan better next time.

Comment: I don't know where I got Sept 10 from. It should have been Aug 31. I've updated my answer above to reflect this date.

Comment: @JLijegren__c - Sep 10th might have been correct, actually.  I created it when it was still api-25 and then a week or two later it upgraded, which might have been sep 10th.

Comment: Aug 31 was when you would have had to refresh your sandbox for it to end up on an "early" instance. The actual upgrade took place on Sept 8.